# Javascript Synchronous Download using window.open

Tags: javascript, window, download, synchronous

My JavaScript web application allows the user to download a file.  I use `window.open(fileUrl)` to accomplish this.  However, when the new window opens, the rest of the code in my application continues to run.  I need my application to wait until the file has completed downloading.

I'm fairly certain that this is not possible using `window.open` because the new window is completely separate from my application.

How can I wait until the file is done downloading before my application code proceeds?

Comment: There is no way to know if a file has completely downloaded in general.

Comment: you have to fetch it to ram and then download it from there. i've never had a download from ram take more than zero seconds, but it can take a bit to fetch and build, which stalls the browser like you want.

Comment: @dandavis - how can I download from ram?  Would simply requesting the data via an AJAX request count as fetching the file to ram?

Comment: ajax. depending on the file, you might need some special sauce to handle binary. once you have the file in ram as a blob, array buffer, string, or whatever, then you can download it using several methods. i consolidate many in a script at http://danml.com/js/download.js.